# List Permissions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions

I am having some issues with what seems to be basic permissions.  I've checked everything I can think of, but can't seem to make it work as desired.

When the user from my SQL user database is assigned to the visitor's group in SP2013, they can see the list, but cannot see any of the actual items (just the headers of each column in the view).

When the user is assigned to the member's group, it works as expected.  They should be able to view all list items.

I'm sure this is something simple, but it is eluding me.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of list is it? If document library, make sure the items are published if publishing is enabled

Comment: I figured out the problem.

The view is configured as a datasheet.  Since the view starts in edit mode, I guess it makes sense that nothing is displayed with view only access since you can't edit anything, but it would be more intuitive if it just displayed it in the same view and didn't let you edit.

Anyway, changing the view to a different type corrected the problem.

Thanks for the input.